# ANR in MessageQueue enqueuemessage, removemessage, next

Tags: java, android

There is a custom view, that posts UI updates. In most cases it's working well, but when I start to massively update UI (scrolling fast) ANR happens.

Even after reviewing MesaggeQueue.java I can't understand how message polling can enter infinite loop. How to safely post updates to UI, or how to avoid ANR while posting?

There is ANR trace:

```java
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Blocked
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x76079d60 self=0xe6ec3000
  | sysTid=6740 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xeb5ac494
  | state=S schedstat=( 77937604266 6358000079 147273 ) utm=7009 stm=784 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff40a000-0xff40c000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at android.os.MessageQueue.removeMessages (MessageQueue.java:813)
- waiting to lock <0x0b1ff8c3> (a android.os.MessageQueue) held by thread 128
  at android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks (Handler.java:587)
  at android.view.View.removeCallbacks (View.java:16993)
  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animatePropertyBy (ViewPropertyAnimator.java:972)
  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animateProperty (ViewPropertyAnimator.java:922)
  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.alpha (ViewPropertyAnimator.java:736)
  at dssl.client.video.v2.videoview.VideoView2$setButtonVisibility$1.run (VideoView2.kt:866)
```

```java
"[351] /channels?sid=a865QKDF" prio=1 tid=128 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x15390f40 self=0xbc798800
  | sysTid=9477 nice=19 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa99eb970
  | state=R schedstat=( 2266974496 124939065 2197 ) utm=208 stm=17 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xa98e8000-0xa98ea000 stackSize=1042KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage (MessageQueue.java:692)
- locked <0x0b1ff8c3> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage (Handler.java:763)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime (Handler.java:715)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.sendMessageAtTime (ViewRootImpl.java:4381)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed (Handler.java:685)
  at android.os.Handler.post (Handler.java:402)
  at android.view.View.post (View.java:16889)
  at dssl.client.video.v2.videoview.VideoView2.showCloudWatermark (VideoView2.kt:318)
```

Post code is trivial, just a bunch of

```
post {
   view.visibilty = View.VISIBLE
}
```